# How would I Have Each TextView display something depending on another variable?

Tags: java, android, textview

I am making an application for teachers that you put in the max number of points and it tells you the percent of each amount wrong. I then would like to use that percentage to make each of the textviews display the grade with the corresponding percentage. So the first column is the amount right out of the max, the second column is the percentage, and the third column is the letter grade. I then have eight rows, but would like to expand that in the future. I know that I would have to an if to say if the percent is between two numbers, settext to a letter grade, but would I have to do the same for every textview, or what other way would there be to do this?

This is the code for what I basically have to far:

```
    MaxInt = Integer.parseInt(number);

    minus1 = MaxInt - 1;
    minus2 = MaxInt - 2;
    minus3 = MaxInt - 3;
    minus4 = MaxInt - 4;
    minus5 = MaxInt - 5;
    minus6 = MaxInt - 6;
    minus7 = MaxInt - 7;
    minus8 = MaxInt - 8;

    float PD1 = (minus1 * 100.0f) / MaxInt;
    float PD2 = (minus2 * 100.0f) / MaxInt;
    float PD3 = (minus3 * 100.0f) / MaxInt;
    float PD4 = (minus4 * 100.0f) / MaxInt;
    float PD5 = (minus5 * 100.0f) / MaxInt;
    float PD6 = (minus6 * 100.0f) / MaxInt;
    float PD7 = (minus7 * 100.0f) / MaxInt;
    float PD8 = (minus8 * 100.0f) / MaxInt;

    int D1 = (int) PD1;
    int D2 = (int) PD2;
    int D3 = (int) PD3;
    int D4 = (int) PD4;
    int D5 = (int) PD5;
    int D6 = (int) PD6;
    int D7 = (int) PD7;
    int D8 = (int) PD8;


    P1 = String.valueOf(D1);
    P2 = String.valueOf(D2);
    P3 = String.valueOf(D3);
    P4 = String.valueOf(D4);
    P5 = String.valueOf(D5);
    P6 = String.valueOf(D6);
    P7 = String.valueOf(D7);
    P8 = String.valueOf(D8);


    TV1.setText(Integer.toString(minus1));
    TV2.setText(Integer.toString(minus2));
    TV3.setText(Integer.toString(minus3));
    TV4.setText(Integer.toString(minus4));
    TV5.setText(Integer.toString(minus5));
    TV6.setText(Integer.toString(minus6));
    TV7.setText(Integer.toString(minus7));
    TV8.setText(Integer.toString(minus8));
    TV9.setText(P1 + "%");
    TV10.setText(P2 + "%");
    TV11.setText(P3 + "%");
    TV12.setText(P4 + "%");
    TV13.setText(P5 + "%");
    TV14.setText(P6 + "%");
    TV15.setText(P7 + "%");
    TV16.setText(P8 + "%");
```

I know that some of that isn't nessesary like converting the float to a integer, then string, but I will fix that when I am done. TV17 - TV24 will be the letter grades.

Comment: you can do it by inflating linear layout programatically in your app. That way you have to create only one textview and data to it like listview

Comment: @cricket_007 I do have all of the first two columns done, but I don't have the third one done, would you like me to post my code?

Comment: Do all scores have the same maximum? This looks like something that could be easily done with a ListView, a custom Adapter, and some `Grade` class. Could you share an example layout of what you are trying to make this look like?